# Mongoose read without schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is there a way to read from MongoDB using Mongoose(for node.js) without defining a schema.

If I only want to print out all the data stored in a collection, like how the terminal command **db.collectionName.find()** works. Can I not pass a schema to achieve that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mongoose expose the [mongodb.DB instance](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/connection.html#connection_Connection-db) 
via `mongoose.connection.db`, so you can use directly the 
[mongodb native driver](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/index.html)

For example, if you want to print out all the data stored in a collection without 
defining schema

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/testDB').then(() => {
    const db = mongoose.connection.db;
    db.collection('collection-name').find().toArray((err, result) => {
        console.log(result)
    });
}).catch(err => console.log(err.message))
```

See mongodb native driver [documentation](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html)
for more examples